# ambiguous call to overload - casting

Tags: c++, casting, compiler-errors, long-integer, code-cleanup

Working on a program, and there's one line of my code that is giving me issues. I was wondering if anyone here may know how to fix this one line of code:

```
long long x;
srand(time(NULL));
x = rand() % 1000;
long long range = pow (2, 60*(pow(2,x)-1)) ;
```

Whenever I run this I get an error stating that there is an ambiguous call to overload. 
I did some research and it seems to have to do with different types (concerning the `long long`). I was thinking there may be a way to cast this in a different way in order to go around this issue, however I'm unsure of how to do this. 
Would anyone happen to have any suggestions on what to do in order to get the second line of code working?

EDIT: I get the following errors:

```
main1.cpp:149: error: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
/usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:343: note: candidate 1: double pow(double, double)
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:357: note: candidate 2: float std::pow(float, float)
main1.cpp:149: error: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
/usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:343: note: candidate 1: double pow(double, double)
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:357: note: candidate 2: float std::pow(float, float)
```

With the method that Luchian suggested the following error that appears is the following:

```
main1.cpp:149: error: call of overloaded 'pow(int, long long int&)' is ambiguous
/usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:343: note: candidates are: double pow(double, double)
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:357: note:                 float std::pow(float, float)
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:361: note:                 long double std::pow(long double, long double)
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:365: note:                 double std::pow(double, int)
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:369: note:                 float std::pow(float, int)
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:373: note:                 long double std::pow(long double, int)
```

Comment: What's the error? http://ideone.com/GO1cT

Comment: Whenever I run this I am getting "error: call of overloaded 'pow(int, long long int&)' is ambiguous"

Comment: Edit your question to include the **full** error message - including the candidates.

Comment: See - an error message can get you a long way. Next time, post it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I just added what I currently get from trying this with Drise's casting version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either:

```
long long range = ::pow (2, 60*(::pow(2,x)-1)) ;
```

or

```
long long range = std::pow (2, 60*(std::pow(2,x)-1)) ;
```

Comment: Tried both methods and I get a slightly altered error message. Updating the original post with the error statement so you can see.

Comment: @Julian now you can cast to `long double`.

Comment: Hmm.. a little confused. I'm trying your second version of the code, would I need to static_cast this during the declaration of range? Hence: "long long range = static_cast<long double>std::pow (2, 60*(std::pow(2,x)-1));"

Comment: Also, I added what the value of x is intended to be, didn't think it would be that important, but upon doing some more experimentation I think it would be helpful to display in original post as well

Comment: Also, whenever I try using your first method I am able to successfully compile, however the numbers that I'm receiving are completely wrong (huge negative numbers). I'm already using a long long, so I'm not sure if there's a slight error at some point earlier in my code or if it has to do with something else currently occurring in this part of the code. While doing some testing however I did notice that the error is occurring inside of the second pow that's inside of the first pow. Whenever it is changed to std::pow is when the ambiguous error is occurring so I'm curious as to why

Answer (score 2):

There are overloaded versions of `pow` for `float` and `double`.  Since you're passing in `long`s, you need to cast to `float` or `double`, but the compiler doesn't know which one you want.

Try changing `2` to `2.0`.  This makes it a `double` and should resolve the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is that `pow` requires the first argument to be not `int`.

The function candidates should be:

```
(1)float pow( float base, float exp );

(2)double pow( double base, double exp );

(3)long double pow( long double base, long double exp );
```

You need:

```
long long range = pow(2.0, 60*(pow(2.0, x)-1));
```

So the compiler can know to use the `double` version of `pow`

Comment: I'm double checking now, one sec.

Comment: I'm thinking that in order to get this to work in my situation I'll need to static_cast it rather than use the C casting style. I tried out your method and the build still ends up failing. The error statement that gets produced I just added to my message.

Comment: I think the ambiguity was from two definitions of `pow` - one from `std`, one from the global namespace.

Comment: @Drise: It's probably be best to cast to a `double` rather than a `float`, since `2.0` is a `double`.